# Mimicking `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible` on a jQuery UI sortable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is a jsFiddle so you can clearly see what I am about to describe:

http://jsfiddle.net/c26SK/5/

I have two boxes. The left hand one is filled with items, items that can be dragged into the right hand box.

Items in the right hand box can be rearranged. Items stack vertically.

Both boxes are a set height. If items go outside the lower bounds of the right hand box, I want a scroll bar to appear.

What I want to do (if its even possible) is this:

As I am dragging items in the right hand box, I want to be able to rearrange the items as I drag the item up and down, however, if I also want to detect if an item has been dragged outside of the right hand box.

Unfortunately all that happens now is the item scrolls inside the right hand box both horizontally and vertically.

Ideally I want something like `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible` which I know isn't possible. Then I would just see if the x,y coordinates of the item is inside the right hand box when it is dropped.

Ive been playing about with appendTo, to see if that could solve the problem, but no luck so far.

Is what I am trying to do achievable? Can anyone help me out? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's far from perfect or even a solution for that matter but I think this is a step in the right direction.

I've added a function to the `out` event which checks if you're dragging the sortable item back onto the sortable list. If not, it appends the item to body. It's not pretty and probably not very efficient.

```
out: function (event, ui) {
    if(!$(event.toElement).hasClass('ui-draggable')&&!$(event.toElement).is('#rightitems')) {
        ui.item.appendTo('body')            
    }
}
```

There are some obvious issues with positioning but hopefully it's something to work with. You'll also have to handle the drop event for the element as I haven't tried any of that with this code

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c26SK/8/)